# Return void after x seconds

Tags: c, arduino

How can I restart the function after x seconds again? What can I add to `return void();` ?

```
void sendSMS(){    
  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS();
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");

  return void();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to re-launch your `sendSMS` function after waited x seconds, use this :

```
int time = x;
sleep(x);
sendSMS();
```

but, don't do it into your `sendSMS` function because there will be infinite loop...
if you want only wait, don't use last line `sendSMS()`

---

eger x saniye sonra, yeniden `sendSMS` islemeyi yapmak istiyorsan,  bunu kullanabilirsin :

```
int time = x;
sleep(x);
sendSMS();
```

fakat, bunu `sendSMS()`'in içinde yapma, yoksa bu isleme'den hiç çikamazsin...
sadece beklemek istiyorsan, son hizayi kullanma `sendSMS()`

Comment: Tesekkürler! Thanks! So `return` will not be used instead that I have to int time and call the function by `sendSMS();`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2nd question:

To return `void` just return nothing like so:

```
  ...
  return;
}
```

Comment: What is the delay time for just return? I want to start it after 30 seconds.